# How to add type FunctionComponent to React functional component using the "function" syntax and not "const"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This works fine:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
const Counter: FunctionComponent = () => <div>hello from Counter</div>;
export default Counter;
```

This has compile error:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
function Counter1(): FunctionComponent {
  return <div>hello from Counter1</div>;
}
export default Counter1;
```

The error says:

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
>   Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: {
>   children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement ReactElement
>   Component)>) | (new (props: any) => Component)>'.ts(2322)

How to write functional component with FunctionComponent type using "function" syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
const Counter: FunctionComponent = () => <div>hello from Counter</div>;
```

`Counter` is of type `FunctionComponent`. That is the desired behavior. But in:

```
function Counter(): FunctionComponent {
  return <div>hello from Counter1</div>;
}
```

`Counter`'s type is a **function that returns a `FunctionComponent`** which is not what you want, and does not fit the function definition.

If you absolutely want to use `function`, you can write it like that:

```
const Counter: FunctionComponent = function() {
  return <div>hello from Counter1</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface with the same name as the function.

```ts
interface Counter extends FunctionComponent {}
function Counter() {
  return <div>hello from Counter1</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A react functional component is function returning a `ReactElement` (this is what several libraries returns in their TypeScript definition, by example `react-router-dom`):

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';

function Counter1(): ReactElement {
  return <div>hello from Counter1</div>;
}
```

Comment: Could you please improve this answer by adding a few words of explanation?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel: A react functional component is function returning a `ReactElement`.